# how to make bootstrap icon text and button vertical center in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the icon, text and button sit in the center of the div vertically.

So, tried to use bootstrap class well, but still not working.  Could someone help me on that?

Here is the image to reference:   [image]

Css part:

```
.brl-icon-size { font-size: 2.5em; }
```

Here is all my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index file</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">
              Sidebar
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 content">
                <div class="well well-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file brl-icon-size"></span>
                    <span>New Message</span>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        Save draft
                        <button>Publish</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.valign-top {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pull-right">
      <span class="valign-top">Save draft</span>
      <button>Publish</button>
</div>
```

[Online Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/WxZ3A/)

#### EDIT 1:

In case you use different `font-size` properties on aligned elements, then you should specify `line-height` property.

[Online Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/G4aQx/)

#### EDIT 2:

It's easier and more correct to just wrap you icon into *small* tag:

```
<small></small>
```

Or simply using custom modifier class:

```
.icon-any-size {
   zoom: 2;
   -moz-transform: scale(2);  /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, forget to say that the font size of the icon is 2.5em; In this case, i dont' know how to make all things vertical middle

Comment: If you add `valign-top` to each element you want to be aligned top, don't you get desired result? Try it?

Comment: yep, I tried, does not work, the tricky part is the icon's font size needs to be 2.5em;

Comment: Specify which icon you're talking about?

Comment: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file brl-icon-size"></span>

Comment: 。。。。。i said the brl-icon-size is 2.5em; not that small

Comment: Ahh, I see. You need to specify corresponding `line-height` property.

Comment: thanks! but When I increase the icon to 2.5em, the text "new message" is not in the middle vertically.

Comment: Justin, it was just a tutorial example so you could understand the matter of the issue. The rest you must come up with by your self. http://jsfiddle.net/G4aQx/1/ I would use other approach, but this one also works though..